# Keeping OEM software after reinstalling OS (Toshiba NB550D)

Tags: windows-7, backup, reinstall, toshiba-laptop, oem

OK, this is a problem I've had a couple of times over the years with laptops (But made worse by current trend of not giving CD's with computer, and instead have hard drive partitions with just a rollback to factory image).

So I got my new Netbook, and I discover Windows Starter doesn't have the ability to change the background (well screw that). I'd already been considering installing Windows 7 Pro, since this is one of the few Netbooks that can easily suport Aero.

I have a copy of Windows 7 pro I got though MSDN Accademic Alliance, (Completely legit)
Now MSDN-AA Product keys don't support Upgrade Anytime, so it's a fresh install for me.

After going though the process to make a bootable USB install disk (from an old iPod)
I use easy transfer to backup my personal settings, and install the OS.

Upon starting it I saw (as expected) none of the Utilities were there. (Normally I uninstall all the utilities, but in this case a couple were worth having. Eco mode etc) I navigated to the `Windows.old/Program Files/Toshiba` (according to plan) where I thought the installers for these util were. A quick survey before had indicated that to be true. Unfortunately my quick glance through a couple coincidentally got only the few that had installers there - most of them didn't.

Right now I'm rolling back to factory settings, Anyone got any clues as to how I can back up this software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OEM pre-installed software can usually be downloaded from the manufacturer's support or drivers website. Just search your model and download the appropriate software and drivers.

Comment: Ah yes, I hadaquick look before, but now i found them, I think: http://www.mytoshiba.com.au/support/computers/nbseries/nb550d/pll5fa-00j01s/download?os=24